# What IP Ranges Are Used By The Azure Resource Manager When Reading Linked ARM Templates in Blob Containers

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have setup an Azure storage account, setting the **Firewalls and virtual networks** to allow access from **Selected networks**. The account is connected to a VNet and subnet where my self-hosted release VMs are connected. When attempting to execute a new deployment with linked ARM templates, the release VMs are able to upload the ARM templates to the blob containers and obtain a SAS token, but the Azure Resource Manager reports "Error: Code=InvalidContentLink; Message=Unable to download deployment content from 'https://...".

All of the **Allow** exceptions are enabled.

[image]

If I change the firewall setting back to **All networks**, the execution completes successfully.

Is there a list of IP address that I should add? For example, Azure DevOps publishes a similar list that I've had to use at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops#ip-addresses-and-range-restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/50886.azure-get-datacenter-ip-address-ranges-via-api.aspx

One challenge here is that there are more IP ranges than we allow whitelisting for, so you need to restrict somehow (e.g. location) for this to work well in prod.  We're working on an alternative solution but don't have an ETA yet.

One option some customers use is to have a separate storage account used only for staging when the files are transient.  That doesn't work for all scenarios (e.g. longer term sharing of files) but may offer some short-term relief.  Happy to chat offline in more detail about options here if it helps.

Comment: what's the current status on this?

Comment: TLDR - nothing new, the requested solution creates more surface area than we like so we don't have a good/secure option at the moment.  Whitelisting seems to be working.  If the use case is only templates (not other artifacts) - bicep uses a model that doesn't require staging and avoids the problem entirely.

Comment: I tried whitelisting all IP addresses I found for Azure Resource Manager via your method, and even tried whitelisting all the IP addresses in here : https://saasedl.paloaltonetworks.com/feeds/azure/public/azureresourcemanager/ipv4 , with no luck. Maybe I am misunderstanding my use case, in which I am deploying via the portal a Logic App in the Standard Plan, and during deployment, the creation of a File Share fails because the targeted storage account allows only accesses from trusted Azure services. I assumed ARM was doing the deployment, and ARM was not a trusted service.

Comment: Is it the logic app that's failing?  If so, then I don't think it's ARM that needs access in that particular step of deployment, but the logic/web app itself...  For that scenario I *think* you have to put the web app in a vnet and open the vnet to the storageAccount...

Comment: So, it is my understanding that the Logic App requires a fileshare to be created in a storage account, and that is a dependency in deploying a Logic App. So, when deploying the Logic App via the portal, it tries to create that fileshare in the targeted storage account, and fails. This happens before starting to deploy the Logic App.

Comment: Ah ok - so that's not ARM that needs access in that case but likely WebApps - which I don't think is on the trusted services list.  I *think* you should be able to put the logic app in a vnet and allow vnet access to the storageAccount...  I would tweet @AzureSupport and see what they say about the scenario.

Comment: *The remote name could not be resolved: 'azuredcip.azurewebsites.net'*

Comment: "Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account." should ideally grant all access needed to ARM